# Python doesn't parse Serial data to an array

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, teensy

I am working on a project in which I have to collect voltages from a teensy 2.0(which I am programming with arduino) and send those voltages to Python. I also have to send the microsecond the data was taken on. I am using PySerial to communicate with the teensy. I first read in all my data to an array of length 3998. I have two other arrays, a `timeData` array, which keeps track of the microseconds, and a `radarData` array, which keeps track of the voltages. Each array carries half the data, or 1999 points.

Sample portion of SerialData:

```
b'1468095384\r\n'
b'0.01\r\n'
```

This will get repeated 1999 times.
The Python code takes these inputs and writes them into and array "SerialData". After it is done reading all the data it separates all the points into the two arrays like so:

```
for i in range (0,3998):
    if(i % 2 == 0):
        radarData[samples] = float(str(SerialData[i], 'utf-8'))
        samples = samples + 1
    else:
        timeData[samples1] = float(str(SerialData[i], 'utf-8'))
        samples1 = samples1 + 1
```

Sample and Sample1 are counter variables.

From printing out `float(str(SerialData[i], 'utf-8'))`, I know that parsing the string as a float works, but whenever I print out `radarData[samples]` or `timeData[samples]`, I just see 0. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what precisely is in `SerialData`?  Drop into the debugger and show us a few items.

Comment: SerialData is the same as the output of the teensy @rrauenza

Comment: Yes, but is that `["b'0.2\r\n'", ...]` or `[b'0.2\r\n', ...]`

Comment: Have you tried doing `SerialData[i].decode()` and not just cast to `str`?

Comment: @rrauenza b'0.2\r\n'

Comment: If this is python3, please tag it python3 in the tags.

Comment: @Quirk I will still have to cast it to a float right? So it will be `float(SerialData[i].decode('utf-8'))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have a false premise on how lists work that is messing you up.  This works:

```
SerialData = [ b'468095384\r\n', b'0.01\r\n'] * 10                              

radarData = []                                                                  
timeData = []                                                                   

for i in range(0,len(SerialData)):                                              
    if(i % 2 == 0):                                                             
        radarData.append(float(str(SerialData[i], 'utf-8')))                    
    else:                                                                       
        timeData.append(float(str(SerialData[i], 'utf-8')))                     

print(radarData)                                                                
print(timeData)
```

(This btw is what we mean when we ask for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

I changed your code to append to empty lists and removed the sample indexes.

It seems that for *your* code to work `SerialData` needs to already be an allocated list with `len(SerialData)` (or more) items.

If you are literally running `SerialData[samples]` when your script exits, then you are looking at a pre-initialized item of some sort in your list.  What value does `samples` have when you look?

Here is my output:

```
[468095384.0, 468095384.0, 468095384.0, 468095384.0, 468095384.0, 468095384.0, 468095384.0, 468095384.0, 468095384.0, 468095384.0]
[0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]
```

And for fun:

```
serialData = [ b'468095384\r\n', b'0.01\r\n'] * 10                              
tmp = list(map(lambda d: float(d), serialData))                   
radarData = tmp[0::2]                                                           
timedata = tmp[1::2]                                                            
print(radarData)                                                                
print(timeData)
```

Comment: I am no longer getting just  zeroes in radarData. Thank you!